# Источник данных с поддержкой LINQ

Tags: ado.net

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь написано источник данных с поддержкой LINQ. Объясните, пожалуйста, эту поддержку надо писать или она есть для всех БД?

Comment: Для всех БД, конечно, нет. На самом деле доступ к данным посредством LINQ возможен благодаря нескольким разным решениям, в частности Entity Framework и LINQ to DB. Погуглите, почитайте, там на страницах написано, какие БД поддерживаются. Вроде как MS SQL, Oracle, Postgres, SQLite, MySQL должны быть определённо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Выложите, пожалуйста, полезные по вашему мнению ссылки.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/, https://linq2db.github.io/